# Estimating number of intersections between point and polygons

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, random-variable

I have a 2D plane (a large rectangle) with a finite size in the x and y direction, which is the field of my problem.

The field is covered by $n$ smaller rectangles that are located randomly within its bounds (the smaller rectangles are free to overlap each other).

If I "sample" the field at some random location I will intersect some number $i$ of smaller rectangles, which happen to overlap this location.

My goal is to estimate the expected number of intersections, with a confidence interval (say 95%).

Is there a way to do this analytically? Any help is appreciated. Lots of detail and laymans terms would be appreciated. As you can probably tell, statistics is not my strong suit.

Edit: Please see comments below for important additional information.

Comment: This will depend on the distribution of the small-rectangle dimensions relative to the dimensions of the field, an the number of small rectangles. Are the rectangles oriented to the axes of the field? (It might help to start with the simpler 1D equivalent problem.)

Comment: So are we trying to find the distribution of the number of rectangles covering a randomly selected point in the region? Seems to me that if you can calculate the total areas covered by no rectangles, exactly one rectangle, two rectangles, ..., then the probabilities would be proportional to these areas. But I'm confused by the confidence part, so perhaps you are not observing the rectangles themselves but instead a sample of outcomes of values of your $i$?

Comment: The rectangles would be small relative to the dimensions of the field. The rectangles (or squares) would have sides with length on the order of 1 metre. We could assume that all rectangles have the same size if that makes it easier. The rectangles are not oriented to the axes of the field, although if it made it easier, we could make that assumption, as it should not substantially change the final answer that much.

Comment: @RussLenth Russ, the goal is to figure out the expected number of intersections at a random sample point (with uncertainty). We have no idea how many rectangles are in the field. We could sample many times to get an average value but a key point that I neglected to mention is that the sampling process is extremely expensive. We do not want to take more samples than are necessary. Therefore, we want to understand the mean and uncertainty (variance or CI) in the number of intersections with increasing samples. We will then make a decision on how many samples are needed. That's the goal.